# How to enable and disable the login button?

Tags: ios

Code:

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
if ([_text.text length] != 0 && [_tex1.text length] != 0)
{
        self.enable.enabled=YES;
}
else {
        self.enable.enabled=NO;
     }
 }
```

My task is if I didn't enter the values in the text box the button should be disabled. While I entered the values in the text box the button should be enabled. But my problem in the code is, the button is not enabled while I entered the values.

Comment: You should enable or disable it on TextField's Delegate rather then button's actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange method because you need to check every character entered than enable and disable your button

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

     if ([_text.text length] != 0 && [_tex1.text length] != 0)
     {
            self.enable.enabled=YES;
     }
     else {
            self.enable.enabled=NO;
         }
     }

    return YES;
}
```

Don't Forgot to set delegate of textField.

```
_text.delegate = self;
_tex1.delgate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code :

```
//1.Implement method

    -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {     
            if ([_text.text length] != 0 && [_tex1.text length] != 0)
        {
                self.enable.enabled=YES;
        }
        else {
                self.enable.enabled=NO;
             }
        }
```

2.set protocol textfield delegate like below

```
    @interface myViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>{

    }
```

.
    3. set the delegate to parent view controller

```
_text.delegate  = self
_tex1.delegate  = self
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
if ([_text.text length] != 0 && [_tex1.text length] != 0)
{
        self.enable.enabled=YES;
}
else 
{
        self.enable.enabled=NO;
}
}
```

Added these line of codes.
Also make sure you add delegates to your textfield

```
_text.delegate = self;
_tex1.delgate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property in `UITextField` "Auto Enable Return Key" to enable the return key automatically whenever you enter text in TextField

```
UitextField->FileInspector->Return Key-> Check box "Auto Enable Return Key"
```